# What about adding a help submission

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

I have a list of SQL statements that can help with determining the 1st and last day of the month, with conversion, etc. Can I post it as a question?

Comment: If you're having trouble with your SQL, you can certainly post your code along with an explanation of what you're having trouble with. You should just check to make sure your question hasn't already been asked on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may post the question and its answer as well. Just make sure to phrase the post as a question that covers the guidelines of a good question and answer it immediately.

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> Can I answer my own question?
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

---

In the Ask a Question page, there is an option for self-answering:

> [image: Self answer checkbox]

Note: Do spend some time to search if there is a duplicate question already present on the site, in which case you should not post your question.